# cant render multiple charts on v-slider-items inside a v-slider

Tags: javascript, charts, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm trying to display multiple charts (from the `chart.js` library),I want each chart to be in a `v-slider-item`.

In the beginning I was told my code wasn't working because I was trying to append the chart `canvas` into the `v-slider-item` before the `DOM` element was updated and therefor the `v-slider-items` weren't rendered, so I executed the chart rendering code inside the `this.nextTick()`

after doing that the code only renders the first chart inside a `v-slider-item` and wont render the rest...

heres a link to a codepen that shows the error:[not rendering v-slider example](https://codepen.io/arjarius88/pen/JjyZJYB?editors=1111)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick fix you may add **eager** prop to your `<v-carousel-item>` component.

---

A small explanation:

Your problem is because Vuetify is using lazy loading of its components. So when the page is loaded, only the block with *the first chart* exists in the DOM. In your code you are trying to get link to your component using `document.getElementById(chart.chartName)`. Unfortunately, it is not possible even with `$nextTick` method - second or third chart will be loaded only when you change carousel active item.

But **eager** prop allows you to force load all charts at the moment when this page is loaded (to be more precise, at *mounted* stage). Please, keep in mind that in production this trick *may* lead to some performance issues.

Maybe it should be better to you to use framework-oriented library like [vue-chartjs](https://vue-chartjs.org/).

Comment: ok thanks so much for the answer,I have a few questions:
1)what do you mean excatly when you say:"second or third chart will be loaded only when you change carousel active item"?
2)even if I use vue-chart.js,wont I still have the same problem with the `<v-carousel-item>` not loading?
thanks

Comment: @leon100, 1. I mean that your second and third charts will be inserted into DOM only on carousel active item change. You don't have element in DOM - so you can't get reference to it using `getElementById`. Maybe [some](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lazy/) of [this links](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-carousel-item/) could explain it better. 2. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with vue-chartjs API and I _just assume_ that this library will suit you better.